# watchOS Show App When Message Received

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find an answer.  I want to send a message from my iOS app to the companion watchOS app and have that app launch.  I see this happen with Messages and various other apps.  How can I achieve this?  I know how to send messages back and forth and can get the iOS app to launch from the watchOS app.

Comment: You can't launch the watch app or bring a suspended/background app to the foreground. You *can* display a notification (and let the user decide to launch the app from the notification). If the existing answer doesn't apple, please [edit] your question to provide more specifics on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Notifications!  My thought process was completely wrong.  Thanks for the key piece of information I needed.